# Why does DateTime.ToString("h") cause exception?

Tags: c#, datetime

Open a watch window

```
new DateTime(2010,01,01).ToString("h")
```

Gives:

> `new DateTime(2010,01,01).ToString("h")` threw an exception of type `System.FormatException`

Yet...

```
new DateTime(2010,01,01).ToString("h ")
```

Gives: "12 "

So why does an extra space stop this format exception from happening?
Is this a bug?

Comment: it's a custom format so you can't add it without space.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's because it thinks it's a [*standard* format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) instead of a [*custom* one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), due to being a single character.

A better way of fixing this is to use `%`:

```
string text = DateTime.Now.ToString("%h");
```

From the docs on custom format strings:

> A custom date and time format string
>   consists of two or more characters.
>   Date and time formatting methods
>   interpret any single-character string
>   as a standard date and time format
>   string. If they do not recognize the
>   character as a valid format specifier,
>   they throw a FormatException. For
>   example, a format string that consists
>   only of the specifier "h" is
>   interpreted as a standard date and
>   time format string. However, in this
>   particular case, an exception is
>   thrown because there is no "h"
>   standard date and timeformat
>   specifier.
>
> To use any of the custom date and time
>   format specifiers as the only
>   specifier in a format string (that is,
>   to use the "d", "f", "F", "g", "h",
>   "H", "K", "m", "M", "s", "t", "y",
>   "z", ":", or "/" custom format
>   specifier by itself), include a space
>   before or after the specifier, or
>   include a percent ("%") format
>   specifier before the single custom
>   date and time specifier.
>
> For example, "%h" is interpreted as a
>   custom date and time format string
>   that displays the hour represented by
>   the current date and time value. You
>   can also use the " h" or "h " format
>   string, although this includes a space
>   in the result string along with the
>   hour. The following example
>   illustrates these three format
>   strings.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I guess that would make sense. I am just working with:

dte.ToString("h ").Trim()

for now to get around the problem.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("%h") - that works for me, many thanks. I should have read the official manual instead of other web sites I guess!